Meaning of "kannst" in "Du kannst mir sehr gefallen."
I ran across "... du kannst mir sehr gefallen." in the song "O, Tannenbaum!" (I'm guessing most people here know these lyrics so I won't bother filling in context.) If you want to say "I really like you" in German then normally you'd say something like "Du gefällst mir sehr," without "können"; at least that's how I'd translate it. The "können/kannst" makes it sound more like "It's possible that I like you very much," which seems less in the holiday spirit. So does "können/kannst" mean something here or is it just filler to make the syllables come out right in the song?

I would read the "können" as a reference to the tree's ability to please and delight the speaker. The tree can delight the speaker very much, proven by how often it has pleased the speaker in the Christmas season:

Oh Tannenbaum, oh Tannenbaum,
du kannst mir sehr gefallen!
Wie oft hat nicht zur Weihnachtszeit
ein Baum von dir mich hoch erfreut!

which means something like

Oh fir tree, oh fir tree,
you are able to delight me very much!
Wasn't it very often that, around Christmas time,
a tree of your kind has pleased me highly!


The "nicht" in these lyrics is a bit tricky as well, by the way. We're talking about meaning 2 at DWDS or meaning 3a at Duden: The speaker affirms the positive meaning ("isn't it like this") and looks for agreement.

So a more literal translation of "gefallen" -- "to be pleasing to" would explain the "kannst". "You are able to be very pleasing to me" may be awkward in English, but it captures the intent of the German lyrics and it seems more like it's more the holiday spirit.

PS. It's interesting that you translated "Tannenbaum" as "fir tree" since the song is known as "O Christmas Tree" in the English speaking world. A "Christmas Tree" can be nearly any conifer (Nadelbaum), though I suppose firs do seem to be above average in terms of being "Christmassy". I'm guessing that in the conversion from German to English, "fir" didn't have the right number of syllables.

@RDBury "O Tannenbaum" was originally not about Christmas at all, but about a diappointed love and about how the fir tree's "leaves" are more faithful to it than a certain woman was to the author of the original song ( https://www.volksliederarchiv.de/tannenbaum-falsch-gemuete/ ). Later someone took only the first original verse and wrote some new ones that refered to the Christmas tree. I guess the English version came after that.

@RDBury The German equivalent of "christmas tree" would actually be "Weihnachtsbaum", and that can be about any "Nadelbaum" as well. A Tanne is _the_stereotypical Weihnachtsbaum, though. But because this question was about language details, I tried to translate more literally. HalvarF already commented on the non-Christmas origins of the lyrics.

@HalvarF - According to Wikipedia the melody dates before Zarnack 's version; it's not clear to me that the original lyrics were even in German. But yes, Zarnack 's version is a lot different. The gist of it, I gather, is that singer's beloved is like a Nachtigall/nightingale, who flits off once summer is over, and not like the fir tree who stays around all year round. In English this might be called a torch song, not a Christmas carol. There are a number of versions in English, but they came after the German version.
